# Printing an array in scala

Tags: scala

I tried to take user input to an array and print it using scala. But there's something wrong.

```
def  abc()={
var n:Int=0
var m:Int=0
var i:Int=0
var j:Int=0
    print("Enter The Length Here:") 
    n=scala.io.StdIn.readInt
    var z= new Array[Int](n)
    while(n>i){
        print("Enter The Num :")        
        m=scala.io.StdIn.readInt
        z[i]=m
        i+=1
    }
    for(j <- 0 to n){
        print(z[j])
        j=j+1
    }
```

} 
abc()

Comment: In _Scala_, array elements are accessed via functions. Hence, you do not use square brackets, but round brackets, when accessing array elements. When reading a value, `x(i)` is equivalent to `x.apply(i)` and retrieves the `i`th element. When setting a value, `x(i) = v` is equivalent to `x.update(i, v)` and sets the `i`th value to `v`. Read the [docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html) for further details. In _Scala_, square brackets are used for specifying generic type information (as in your declaration of `z`).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a version in more idiomatic Scala:

```
def abc() = {
  print("Enter The Length Here:")
  val n: Int = scala.io.StdIn.readInt

  val z = (1 to n).map{ i =>
    print(s"Enter value $i: ")

    scala.io.StdIn.readInt
  }

  z.foreach(print)
}

abc()
```

No `var` or `for` required

Answer (score 2):

Here is correct version of your code snippet:

```
def abc() = {
  var n: Int = 0
  var m: Int = 0
  var i: Int = 0
  var j: Int = 0

  print("Enter The Length Here:")
  n = scala.io.StdIn.readInt
  var z = new Array[Int](n)

  while (n > i) {
    print("Enter The Num :")
    m = scala.io.StdIn.readInt
    z(i) = m
    i += 1
  }
  for (j <- 0 until n) {
    print(z(j))
  }
}

abc()
```

1. Use `(index)` instead of `[index]` to get element by index in `Array` or assign value.
2. Using `for (j <- 0 to n)` isn't correct, because you can get `ArrayIndexOfBoundException` use `until` instead of `to`, so `for (j <- 0 until n)` is correct.
3. There is no need to increment like `j = j + 1`, because you can't reassign `val` and `for` will traverse all element from 0 to n. So your `j` will be `0, 1 ... n -1`